# What pattern prefer to use when combine Laravel and Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

As I know, there are 2 ways to use Vuejs in view: inline-template and component.

***#1. Inline-template***

I gonna use the code from series [Let's Build A Forum with Laravel and TDD](https://laracasts.com/series/lets-build-a-forum-with-laravel) for express my point.

ThreadsController:

```
public function show($channel, Thread $thread, Trending $trending)
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            auth()->user()->read($thread);
        }

        $trending->push($thread);

        $thread->increment('visits');

        return view('threads.show', compact('thread'));
    }
```

View (threads.show)

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('head')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/vendor/jquery.atwho.css">
@endsection

@section('content')
    <thread-view :thread="{{ $thread }}" inline-template>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8" v-cloak>
                    @include ('threads._question')

                    <replies @added="repliesCount++" @removed="repliesCount--"></replies>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>
                                This thread was published {{ $thread->created_at->diffForHumans() }} by
                                <a href="#">{{ $thread->creator->name }}</a>, and currently
                                has <span
                                        v-text="repliesCount"></span> {{ str_plural('comment', $thread->replies_count) }}
                                .
                            </p>

                            <p>
                                <subscribe-button :active="{{ json_encode($thread->isSubscribedTo) }}" v-if="signedIn"></subscribe-button>

                                <button class="btn btn-default"
                                        v-if="authorize('isAdmin')"
                                        @click="toggleLock"
                                        v-text="locked ? 'Unlock' : 'Lock'"></button>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </thread-view>
@endsection
```

And the ThreadView Component doesn't include `<template></template>` tag.

Taylor still uses the blade as default and just import Vuejs component when needed.

***#2. Component:*** Same above but all the stuff in view will be brought into `<template></template>` tag.

Which way should I prefer to use in my project? I can't see the advantages and disadvantages of both ways. The only thing I can see, if I use the inline-template, I can take advance of Laravel Collection helper or blade directive (@auth, @guest).

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the complexity of your interface you intend to implement. Personally, I use Vuejs with the whole of its capabilities as my frontend layer of my application. In this case, you can employ **Vue Router** to transform more smoothly between your pages and also **Vuex** as the storage management in your frontend layer.

To sum up, if you want to implement a **SPA** (Single Page Application) choose the second way. But if you want to just use limited capabilities of Vuejs continue the first way.